# Magento 2: Need to re-save all products after re-assigning source

Tags: magento2

so I deactived all MSI-related modules and found out that it still needed it for another module, so I activated it again.

Then the default source that was created by the data-migration from M1 to M2 was gone after that.
So I created a new source and added all products to that source, however all the products were still 'out of stock' on the frontend. After re-saving a product, it is displayed properly on the frontend.

Therefore I need to re-save all products. Is there a fast way to do so or can I do something else?

Btw: I tried reindexing, upgrading etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Write a CLI command to save all products again

```
$storeId = 1;
$productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('id')
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->load();

$i = 1;
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);

    $product->save();
    echo $i.". Saved product ".$product->getName()." with product id ".$productId. "\n";

    $i++;
}
```